# Hows to make a DB2 table read-only?

Tags: db2

We need to test how an application will fail when the DB2 database cannot be written to.

What is the easiest way to make a DB2 table read-only? Is this considered locking?

Thanks in advance,
Bert

Comment: The error returned to the application will be different, depending on _why_ the table cannot be updated, so you'll need to specify the exact scenario you are trying to reproduce. You _can_ lock a table, but that only tests one specific scenario: what happens when the table is locked. Depending on how the database is configured, that may not even return an error, the application will simply wait indefinitely for the lock to be released.

Comment: You could have an unauthorised user try to update - that should fail! What's the app written in?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to test it:

- Use `LOCK TABLE` and put it in "exclusive" mode
- REVOKE the privilege to INSERT or UPDATE on that table from the test user
- REVOKE the privilege to connect to that database
- Change or remove TCP/IP access to the database
- ...

There are many testing scenarios and most of them will result in a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on insert, delete or update on the table that will raise asignal automatically for these operations. This will make the tBle as read only and the security remain the same

Answer (score 0):

On the DB2 commands screen try

```
-START  DATABASE(yourDB) SPACENAM(tsname) ACCESS(RO)
```

Source [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.comref/src/tpc/db2z_cmd_startdatabase.dita).

Comment: You may want to mention that this solution is specific to DB2 for z/OS; it's unknown what version or platform the OP was asking about.